# Find image of complex function: $w(z) = z+i\bar{z}$ defined from $\mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I found that, $w(\mathbb{C}) = \left \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Re(z) = \Im(z) \right\}$, is that correct?

In such case,

- does it mean the resulting image set is a line?
- Any example of a bijection between this image set and any other set?

Comment: It is correct and it is indeed a line.

Comment: Yes it looks correct and the image is the first diagonal i.e. a line. The map is surjective because $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\,w(x(1+i)/2)=x(1+i)$ but it is not injective because $w(x/2)=w(x(1+i)/2=x(1+i)$

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Is it possible to find a bijective function that maps $w(\mathbb{C})$ into another known set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=a+bi, \bar{z}=a-bi\to z+i\bar{z}=a+bi+ai+b=a+b+i(a+b)$. Then the image is the line $L=\{z=a+bi\in\mathbb {C}:a=b\}$. A bijection between this line and another set is $f:L\to\mathbb {R}, f(a+bi)=a$.